# How to get the remainder of each item in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that has these columns:

- Product Title
- Product Sort
- Quantity ( can be both income and outcome )
- Price
- IncomeOutcome ( can be 1 or 2, 1 means **Income** 2 means **Outcome** )

And I need to query the remainder of items for each of my individual Products.

For example I have the following rows:

| Title | Sort | Quantity | Price | IncomeOutcome |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Beer | Light | 100 | 8$ | 1 |
| Beer | Light | 60 | 8$ | 2 |
| Beer | Dark | 80 | 9$ | 1 |
| Beer | Dark | 50 | 9$ | 2 |

**1st** row means that I'm *receiving* 100 Dark Beer for 8$

**2nd** row means that I'm *selling* 60 Dark Beer for 8$

How can I write a query that would return a row like this for **each one** of my table rows:

| Title | Remainder |
| --- | --- |
| Light Beer | 40 |
| Dark Beer | 30 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
   Title
   , Sort
   , SUM(Quantity * IIF(IncomeOutcome = 1, 1, -1)) AS Remainder
FROM t
GROUP BY Title, Sort
```